# Only NGINX or Apache + Nginx

Tags: nginx

I need more speed output from my servers and I am very very confused.  I have only dynamic contents on my server.  With traffic like 6K per second.

Please guide me.

Comment: This question need a lot more clarification. Only dynamic? No images? When you say traffic do you mean 6,000 visitors a second? This doesn't sound like a normal web site, is this a special application?

Comment: This is an auction portal ?

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion would be..

Nginx Proxy/Balance to Dynamic content on Apache
Nginx Serve all static content..

I have worked on a reverse auction site using this technique and say alot of throughput..

What language is your backend in???

Answer (score 0):

The "Nginx HTTP Server" book advises eliminating Apache to improve performance. The dynamic content can be served through a FastCGI server, or if it's in Perl, a backend PSGI server like [Starman](https://metacpan.org/module/Starman).